# Project Xcode and git branch

Tags: android, ios, xcode, git

(Sorry if I make spelling mistakes, I'm French)

Hi everybody ! :)

I work on iOS and Android projects. My team and I use the same code for each customers and make changes depending to requests of each. 
On Android, we create one new branch for each customer from master and made all the changes include the name.
But on iOS, I don't know how to process because if I change the name on a branch of the project it's certainly impact the base project on the branch master, don't know ? Some posts explain I can create a library to have the common code in one place... but it does not come back to the same ? The project name have to change in any case ?

So my real question is : How can I create an iOS project with another name in the same git project on another branch ?

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: You can use targets for this, each target is a sepcific version for the client. You can also make changes by include `.m` in the client specific target.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! :)